# How to start plutus pioneers course on canvas

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Today is the course start date for pioneers program.
But when i login to canvas, i am not getting any content.
I checked the announcement board and it just shows me up course syllabus and the teacher's bio.
how am i supposed to start learning within the canvas?
thanks!

Comment: This is to confirm that I see the same thing, and it seems there is no info on how to proceed.

Comment: Hi Shimelis! The first module will be posted on Thursday, but in the meantime pioneers are working on dev env setup-- discussions occurring in Discord. NOTE-- Generally avoid posting questions about how the course is run here in CSE, as such questions tend to have short term utility. I realize initial Canvas setup was confusing, a recent update there + getting into discord should make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first lesson will be released on Thursday 13 as mentioned in the communication on Discord. In the meantime you can start with the setup of the Plutus environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes today is the beginning of the Plutus Pioneer 3rd version. However, there are some technical set ups to go through before the first lecture is published, which will occur on Thursday 13th. Some news will come up soon, but I suggest you have a look at

https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/Ubuntu.html

Where you can sort your set up for your preferred OS (lectures are outdated but the set up should be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Igodlab and @Antonio - CSP.
I am thinking to continue with with playground setup.
I didn't want a local setup on my machine.
What do you suggest on this?
pros and cons kind of advice.